# Unable to construct AWS S3 signature for method in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this Python code where I am trying to create signed HTTPS calls to AWS. (From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html)

However I get a response of

`403 The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method" from the server.`

I can run the command from the AWS CLI so I know that my keys are valid and I can't find anything online that looks different than what I currently have. Also I've looked into Boto3 and it can't do what I want.

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
import requests # pip install requests

# Standard Variables
aws_service = 's3'
aws_region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'

signedHeaders = 'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'

def test():
  method = 'GET'
  requestParameters = 'max-keys=2'
  path = '/'
  bucket = 'my-test-bucket'
  signatureRequest(method, requestParameters, path, bucket)

# Creates the Authorization Header for the request
def signatureRequest(method, requestParameters, objPath, bucket):
  accessKey = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESSKEY_ID')
  secretKey = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESSKEY')
  if accessKey is None or secretKey is None:
    print 'No access key is available.'
    sys.exit()

  # Variables
  host= aws_service + '.' + aws_region + '.amazonaws.com'
  t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  amzDate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
  dateStamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')
  canonicalUri = objPath
  canonicalQuerystring = 'Action=' + requestParameters
  payloadHash = hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest() # hash is always '' for GET

  #--- Create the request (Task 1) ---
  canonicalHeaders = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-content-sha256:' + payloadHash + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzDate + '\n'
  canonicalRequest = method + '\n' + canonicalUri + '\n' + canonicalQuerystring + '\n' + canonicalHeaders + '\n' + signedHeaders + '\n' + payloadHash
  print '--- Canonical Request (Task 1) ---'
  print 'method \ncanonicalUri \ncanonicalQuerystring \ncanonical_headers \nsigned_headers \npayload_hash \n'
  print '%s \n\n' % canonicalRequest

  #--- String to Sign (Task 2) ---
  credentialScope = dateStamp + '/' + aws_region + '/' + aws_service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
  stringToSign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzDate + '\n' +  credentialScope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonicalRequest).hexdigest()

  #--- Signature (Task 3) ---
  signingKey = getSignatureKey(secretKey, dateStamp, aws_region, aws_service)
  signature = hmac.new(signingKey, (stringToSign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

  #--- authorizationHeader (Task 4) ---
  authorizationHeader = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + accessKey + '/' + credentialScope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signedHeaders + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
  requestUrl = endpoint + '?' + canonicalQuerystring # Creates the URL

  #The 'host' header is added automatically by the Python 'requests' library.
  headers = {'x-amz-content-sha256': payloadHash, 'x-amz-date':amzDate, 'Authorization':authorizationHeader}

  sendRequest(requestUrl, headers)

# Key Signing Functions
def sign(key, msg):
  '''
  Copied from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html
  '''
  return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
  '''
  Copied from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html
  '''
  kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
  kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
  kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)    
  kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
  print '%s' % kSigning
  return kSigning

# Sends the request to AWS and prints the return code
def sendRequest(url, headers):
  r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  print 'Response from AWS: %d\n' % r.status_code
  print r.text
```

Comment: I'd be curious to know what boto3 can't do for your needs. Boto3 covers all APIs in AWS. Also, it handles signatures for you. If you're going to build signatures yourself, you're about to enter a huge world of pain and misery. You should definitely look deeper into boto3.

Comment: `canonicalQuerystring = 'Action=' + requestParameters` isn't correct. The string `Action=` does not belong here.  The S3 API is REST, not Query.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

Comment: `requestParameters` also needs to be sorted lexically, although in this case you appear to have only one.

Comment: From my understanding, boto3 can't do what I want @spg, what my end goal here is to be able to generate signed URL requests of commands such as GET Bucket (List Objects) v2. I'm open to using boto3 if there is a way to do that, however, I was enjoying using this as practice for HTTPS responses. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure there's a class you could reuse in boto3 (or botocore) that would handle the signing for you. Just curious, why do you need to generate signed URLs for GET Bucket? Maybe there's an alternative.

Comment: All I want to do is be able to generate v4 signed GET and POST requests with arguments, I have no HTTP experience or anything like that at all and was given this as a task for a project and I'm very lost